# Auto-refresh Lightning component from one page refreshing entire community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili

With respect to my **[Previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189348/auto-refresh-napili-communitys-standard-page-once-in-every-five-minutes)**, this custom refresh lightning component is on home page of the community. But, this is refreshing all my entire community no matter what page I am on. How to get rid of this? Like, how to make only the home page get refreshed?

Comment: check for location.href and set a condition for the home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of my friend, @glls, I got the idea to make a condition by utilizing `window.location.href;` and also added some extra effort: `if(currentUrl.endsWith("/s/")` to get it stick to the home page alone. Here is complete working code:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    console.log(currentUrl);
    if(currentUrl.endsWith("/s/")) {
          //Callback function
   } else {
         //do something 
  }
```

Note: Make sure to use `unrender` to stop/kill the setInterval method whenever you leave the component's page. That way, every time you navigate to a different page, setInterval gets killed and will not trigger on your newly opened page/window. Hope this helps someone who visits this post.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a variable for the current url, for example:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
if(currentUrl.includes("home"){
    //execute your callback function
}
else{
    //don't do it =P
}
```

Comment: In the URL for Home page, I only see: https://sandbox.cs30.force.com/projName/s/. And every other page is like the extension for this home page's URL. How to have a conditional check here.

Comment: instead of home you can set the condition to match the url, doesnt need to be includes("home"), the above is just for reference purposes =P

Comment: lol. I can do that. But, this should be standard even if I deploy this component to Production. I shouldn't be going back to code and make a change for the URL :) Thus wondering.

Comment: use a regex for patterns then ;)

Comment: Don't you think that's complicated? At least for me. (-'- . -'-)

Comment: Not really. tbh, i'm not a regex guru, but you can find a lot on stackoverflow for the pattern(s) you require, and validate using a [Regex Validating tool](https://www.regexpal.com/)

Comment: I am eager to know if I can do it without regex. Because, I am not good at it, and it may kill my time for trying to figure out the working pattern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65298/discussion-between-glls-and-arnold-jr).